# Can't improve Wordpress website performance

Tags: wordpress, performance, performance-testing

I'm trying to work in this website performance: http://www.actsinmotion.com/

I cleaned and optimized the database, tried to combine the most css and js files I could into one. Tried to get rid of all unnecessary elements, minified, compressed, added expire header, caching functionality, tried to follow all Yslow and gtmetrix, scored A in both and even got the result of the page as taking 3.2s to load.

However, when I actually go to the website, it takes up to 5-8s to load. It's too slow and I have no more ideas of what it could be. Can any one of you give me a hint here?

Comment: It's your host, look at your waterfall in GTMetrix, seriously 1.5s for a 6.7kb image? The site is optimized well, hell 88% in YSlow is quite good for WP. That site should be 1-2 seconds at the slowest. The whole bottleneck is serving images and your images are small. Our site has twice the size of yours and loads in the same time on GTMetrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've done a great job optimising the frontend of the website!

What you probably need to look at is some backend functionality. PageSpeed, GTMetrix etc. look at how quickly your page loads once it initially makes it to the browser. If your server is slow at processing the initial request (eg. there's a lot of plugins it has to run through, or it's just a slow server), then speeding up the frontend will only ever help so much.

I've [posted a general answer to a similar query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223305/does-heavy-theme-and-plugins-affect-servers-response-time/223306#223306) on Wordpress StackExchange before. Have a look at that and see if some of the the suggestions in there - particularly using [Plugin Profiler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/) - help you speed up your site.

In the end it may also help to look at your host. Some shared hosts will pack their servers high, and while it usually means they can sell cheap plans, the performance will suffer as a result. If you're with one of these hosts, try to find one that costs maybe $10-$15 a month more, and you'll *probably* find performance increases as a result.